# What pattern is this refactoring?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have an example with a bunch of logic in my GUI class (winforms).  I am going to refactor that so that there is no logic in the gui and a separate class holds all the logic.

What is that pattern?  Say I had a form class called AddAddressForm, what would you call the associated file that holds the logic?  AddAddressMediator (doesn't quite fit that pattern), if I was doing WPF I would call it the ViewModel (but I am not).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds something like model-view-controller without the model part.

Comment: How MVC is possible without Model

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its called anything.  I've tried doing that sort of thing in the past with Windows Forms, but unfortunately it didn't really work:

For each form I had another class called something like `MyFormLogic` that supposedly contained all of my logic for the form, with the form itself just containing a load of methods and events for manipulating the form (things like an `AddButtonClicked` event, and a `AllItems` collection property)

It seemed like a brilliant idea at the time (Yay easy unit testing!), but what actually happened is the `MyFormLogic` class became just as big and messy as before, and now I had a whole lot of extra pointless code exposing the extra methods events in my *actual* form class. (Also creating an instance of forms was a pain)

I'd recommend that instead you work on refactoring out as much logic as possible into lots of smaller classes that do 1 thing, rather than 1 extra class which deals with all forms logic (Its difficult to explain what I mean without some examples)

Answer (score 2):

By the example given , it seems that your object shares some kind of common data.

Look at the [Flyweight Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFlyweight.aspx) then.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is called Model-View-Presenter pattern. although it is commonly used in asp.net, it should be applied to WinForm as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Martin Fowler splits original MVP pattern into 2 patterns ,  [Supervising Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) and [Passive View](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html), But I still like its original name , MVP.

Answer (score 1):

it depends type of logic , say you have Conditonal Logic and you create different object from it , so seprating this in a new class will be pointing to Factory Method.

2- If you have complex algorithms in your class and you seprate it another class/s , you most probably using Strategy Pattern.

lot of other combinations also possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's Model-View-Controller (MVC). In your example, the Model is the Address, the View is the dialog, and the Controller just mediates events from the dialog to the Address object.

Note: you may omit the Controller for really simple situations, but *don't* if you ever want automated unit-tests; the separation (via interfaces) will pay off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is called Humble View.

For more details and different takes on it, see the [Humble View section of the GUI Architectures page on martinfowler.com](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is still the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, which isn't specific to WPF. The core tenet is that the ViewModel contains state and logic, and the View constantly synchronizes itself with the ViewModel. This is nice and easy with WPF bindings, but they aren't a prerequisite; any stateful UI can utilize MVVM. The Forms flavor of the pattern can get quite wordy on the view side.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your basic separation of concerns by breaking out the view and functionality into different files. Not really sure if it really falls under any sort of pattern per say, but it does remind me of web forms a liitle bit with the views and code behinds.